# Fill color with animation

Tags: jquery, css, html, canvas, html5-canvas

Fill color canvas dynamic with animation. I have created canvas cylinder and it was filling the color. I need animation when I fill the color dynamically Example (slowly filling it).

I have did search in google and I got the result as put animate :fadein / ease in the animation function.

But nothing working for me

```
var perc = 0;
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#my_input").focusout(function (event) {
         if ($("#my_input").val().indexOf("%") != -1) {

            if ($.isNumeric($("#my_input").val().replace('%', ''))) {

                // Allow only backspace and delete
                if (event.keyCode == 46 || event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 37) {
                    //$("#myCanvas").animate({ opacity: 0.25 });
                } else {
                    // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
                    if (event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                    }
                }
                perc = parseInt($("#my_input").val().replace('%', '')) / 100;
                draw();
            }
        } else {
            alert('Value in %');
        }
    });
});

function draw() {
    maxWidth = 180;
    maxHeight = 140;
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    var x = 190;
    var y = 260;

    context.fillStyle = '#f2f2f2';
    context.beginPath();
    context.rect(x - maxWidth / 2, y - maxHeight, maxWidth, maxHeight);
    context.fill();

    var per = perc;
    if (per > 1) perc = 1;
    // fill

    context.fillStyle = 'yellow';

    context.beginPath();
    context.rect(x - maxWidth / 2, y - maxHeight * perc, maxWidth, maxHeight * perc);

    context.fill();

    drawCylinder(100, 100, 180, 180);
    context.beginPath();

}(function () {
    var lastTime = 0;
    var vendors = ['webkit', 'moz'];
    for (var x = 0; x < vendors.length && !window.requestAnimationFrame; ++x) {
        window.requestAnimationFrame = window[vendors[x] + 'RequestAnimationFrame'];
        window.cancelAnimationFrame = window[vendors[x] + 'CancelAnimationFrame'] || window[vendors[x] + 'CancelRequestAnimationFrame'];
    }

    if (!window.requestAnimationFrame) window.requestAnimationFrame = function (callback, element) {
        var currTime = new Date().getTime();
        var timeToCall = Math.max(0, 16 - (currTime - lastTime));
        var id = window.setTimeout(function () {
            callback(currTime + timeToCall);
        },
        timeToCall);
        lastTime = currTime + timeToCall;
        return id;
    };

    if (!window.cancelAnimationFrame) window.cancelAnimationFrame = function (id) {
        clearTimeout(id);
    };
}());
//the below code is to generate Cylinder object -- Mahadevan
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

var degreeAngle = 0;
requestAnimationFrame(animate);

function drawRotatedCylinder(x, y, w, h, degreeAngle) {
    context.save();
    context.translate(x + w / 10, y + h / 10);
    context.rotate(degreeAngle * Math.PI / 180);
    drawCylinder(-w / 10, -h / 10, w, h);
    context.restore();
}

function drawCylinder(x, y, w, h) {
    context.beginPath(); //to draw the top circle
    for (var i = 0 * Math.PI; i < 2 * Math.PI; i += 0.01) {

        xPos = (x + w / 2) - (w / 2 * Math.sin(i)) * Math.sin(0 * Math.PI) + (w / 2 * Math.cos(i)) * Math.cos(0 * Math.PI);

        yPos = (y + h / 8) + (h / 8 * Math.cos(i)) * Math.sin(0 * Math.PI) + (h / 8 * Math.sin(i)) * Math.cos(0 * Math.PI);

        if (i == 0) {
            context.moveTo(xPos, yPos);
        } else {
            context.lineTo(xPos, yPos);
        }
    }
    context.moveTo(x, y + h / 8);
    context.lineTo(x, y + h - h / 8);

    for (var i = 0 * Math.PI; i < Math.PI; i += 0.01) {
        xPos = (x + w / 2) - (w / 2 * Math.sin(i)) * Math.sin(0 * Math.PI) + (w / 2 * Math.cos(i)) * Math.cos(0 * Math.PI);
        yPos = (y + h - h / 8) + (h / 8 * Math.cos(i)) * Math.sin(0 * Math.PI) + (h / 8 * Math.sin(i)) * Math.cos(0 * Math.PI);

        if (i == 0) {
            context.moveTo(xPos, yPos);

        } else {
            context.lineTo(xPos, yPos);
        }
    }
    context.moveTo(x + w, y + h / 8);
    context.lineTo(x + w, y + h - h / 8);
    context.strokeStyle = '#ff0000';
    context.stroke();
    context.fillStyle = 'yellow';

    context.fill();
}

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(draw);
    context.animate({"Fill":yellow},Slow);      
    drawRotatedCylinder(100, 100, 180, 180);

    draw();
}
```

When I gave context.animate line above drawRotateCylinder I am getting error

Here I don't want to my rotatecylinder just an animation required when I enter Percentage value in the textbox filling the cylinder.

Thank you in advance
Maha

Comment: what do you mean, "fill". As in draw the entire canvas different colors and "fade" the whole canvas towards your desired color? Or fill as "fill it like paint was being poured into a glass"?

Comment: hi @MarcB thanks for replying when I am entering the value in the text box for example 10% the color has fill from bottom to top Example (Poured into a glass)I tried putting animation in the animate function but it was not working me

Comment: that's not something you can flood fill. you'd need to draw individual horizontal lines from the bottom upwards. or "drag" another box with the appropriate color over top of your main canvas. e.g. like sliding two pieces of paper together.

Comment: hi i am new to this canvas animating can you explain me little bit in depth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to draw only inside a cylinder container is to make the container a clipping region.

This way all the fluid will be drawn only inside the cylinder container.

[image]

Here's example code and a Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/Ndmvj/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>
<script>
$(function(){

    // canvas related variables
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var cw=canvas.width;
    var ch=canvas.height;

    // general variables
    var PI=Math.PI;
    var PI2=PI*2;

    // cylinder related variables
    var cx=cw/2;
    var cy=ch/2;
    var width=65;
    var height=100;
    var fillY=cy+height/2+5;
    var w2=width/2;
    var h2=height/2;
    var h4=height/4;
    var h8=height/8;
    var h16=height/16;
    var ytop=-h2+h8;
    var cpYtop=-h2-h16;
    var ybottom=h2-h8;
    var cpYbottom=h2+h16;
    var degreeAngle,rAngle,dx,dy,r,a,xx,yy;

    // start the cylinder upright (at 0 degree angle)
    setContainerAngle(0);

    // start the animations
    requestAnimationFrame(animateFill);

    // animate filling the cylinder
    function animateFill(){
        if(fillY>cy-height/2+h8){
            requestAnimationFrame(animateFill);
        }else{
            requestAnimationFrame(animateEmpty);
        }
        draw();
        drawPouring(cx,0,fillY);
        fillY-=0.50;
    }

    // animate emptying the cylinder
    function animateEmpty(){
        if(degreeAngle>-91){
            requestAnimationFrame(animateEmpty);
        }else{
            fillY=cy+height/2+5;
            requestAnimationFrame(animateToBeginning);
        }
        draw();
        drawPouring(xx,yy,ch);    
        setContainerAngle(degreeAngle-0.50);
    }

    // animate rotating the empty cylinder back to upright
    function animateToBeginning(){
        if(degreeAngle<=0){
            requestAnimationFrame(animateToBeginning);
        }else{
            setContainerAngle(0);
            requestAnimationFrame(animateFill);
        }
        draw();
        setContainerAngle(degreeAngle+1);
    }


    // draw the scene (background, cylinder, liquid in cylinder)
    function draw(){

        ctx.fillStyle="gray";
        ctx.fillRect(0,0,cw,ch);

        ctx.save();

        defineFillOutline(cx,cy,width,height,degreeAngle);

        if(degreeAngle>=-90){
            ctx.clip();
            ctx.fillStyle='gold';
            ctx.fillRect(0,Math.max(fillY,yy),cw,ch);
        }

        ctx.restore();

        drawContainer(cx,cy,width,height,degreeAngle);

    }

    // draw the liquid being poured in a vertical stream
    function drawPouring(xx,yy,yyy){
        ctx.save();
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(xx,yy);
        ctx.lineTo(xx,yyy);
        ctx.lineWidth=5;
        ctx.shadowColor="gold";
        ctx.shadowBlur=8;
        ctx.strokeStyle="gold";
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.restore();
    }

    // define the clipping region (which is the cylinder)
    function defineFillOutline(x,y,w,h,degrees){
        ctx.save();
        ctx.translate(x,y);
        ctx.rotate(degreeAngle*PI / 180);
        //
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(-w2,ytop);
        ctx.bezierCurveTo( -w2,cpYtop, w2,cpYtop, w2,ytop);
        ctx.lineTo(w2,h2-h8);
        ctx.bezierCurveTo( w2,cpYbottom, -w2,cpYbottom, -w2,ybottom);
        ctx.closePath();
        //
        ctx.restore();
    }

    // draw the cylinder at the specified angle
    function drawContainer(cx,cy,width,height,degreeAngle){
        //
        defineFillOutline(cx,cy,width,height,degreeAngle);
        //
        ctx.save();
        ctx.translate(cx,cy);
        ctx.rotate(degreeAngle*PI / 180);

        // this is the top-outer lip of the cylinder
        ctx.moveTo(-w2,-h2+h8);        
        ctx.bezierCurveTo( -w2,-h4, w2,-h4, w2,-h2+h8);
        ctx.strokeStyle="royalblue";
        ctx.lineWidth=2;
        ctx.stroke();
        //
        ctx.restore();
    }

    // change the angle of the cylinder
    function setContainerAngle(degrees){
        degreeAngle=degrees;
        rAngle=degreeAngle*Math.PI/180;
        dx=width/2;
        dy=height/2-height/8;
        r=Math.sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy);
        a=Math.atan2(dy,dx)+Math.PI+rAngle;
        xx=cx+r*Math.cos(a);
        yy=cy+r*Math.sin(a);
    }

}); // end $(function(){});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: hi @markE thanks for your awesome code is that possible to do dynamic when I enter some value it has to fill the color inside cylinder.

Comment: Sure.  The fillY variable determines how much fill there is in the cylinder.  The fluid is "empty" when fillY==cy+height/2 and is "full" when fillY==cy+height/2+h8.  You can dynamically adjust fillY to any value between empty and full.  Then call draw() to display the cylinder at your specified fillY.  Good luck with your project!

Comment: hi @markE I am really worried how I will complete the above one thanks for providing me solution is that possible can you able to update it in fiddle and one small query how to hide the golden color from top (it is like pouring in glass) but when i enter the value in textbox it has to fill automatically

Comment: Hi @markE I got how to hide golden color that's pouring from top I have hide the code 
    ctx.lineTo(xx, yyy); thanks

Comment: The "pouring" was just an added effect that can be eliminated:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/KHkRX/ -- It's late here...got to get some sleep.  Cheers!

Comment: Hi when I tried for dynamic it was not working the way what i want can  anyone help me on the same

Comment: Hi @markE can you help for the dynamic fill animation i have tried but nothing works

Comment: I'll try.  Here's the simplest example that just draws the cylinder and lets the user dynamically adjust the amount of fill using a range control:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/yhm4c/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57349/discussion-between-user3820621-and-marke).